# C++ Metro UI Tiles

Tags: visual-c++, microsoft-metro

Is there any libraries to make the Metro tiled interface in Visual C++/MFC?

That is, 
If you are going to deploy the App. on Windows XP, the library would emulate the UI elements of Metro in MFC/C++ in your App.

There are currently C# libraries which emulate the MetroUI but none in Visual C++/MFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that BCGSoft is going to implement this control: they reported about it on their [forum](http://www.bcgsoft.com/cgi-bin/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=5922)

Answer (score 1):

the latest BCGSuite for MFC version 18.0 from BCGSoft has this features:

- http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour327.htm
- http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour329.htm
- http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour328.htm

It's not free, but very good looking